# Run Time Fatal Error

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting this error on my application when i hit hello button:

[image: error in my code]

Comment: Please do not post image of code. Instead post the actual code. If you want to post images of storyboard, those are fine.

Answer (score 1):

This crash is because of you forgot to set IBoutlet with Output UILabel with UI interface

So you need to set IBOutlet

> select Output Label from storyboard and then right longpress with drag from [image] 
>   to 
>   [image]

after end gesture you get output uilabel then connect with

Comment: can u describe more.im new to xcode!!

Answer (score 0):

kindly check outlets of ur textField (input textField)it  is not connected to your storybord so connect it and then try it

Comment: Not Working at all

Comment: @ShafranNaizer kindly check outlets of ur textFields input textField is not connected to your storybord so connect it

Comment: @ShafranNaizer   https://supereasyapps.com/blog/2016/3/1/60-how-to-create-outlets-and-actions-in-xcode-using-swift .   refer this video to set outlet

Comment: Great It Works Thank You

Comment: @ShafranNaizer ur welcome and it would be cool if you upvote my answer :)

Comment: yeah sure upvote my quiz pls

Comment: @MaheshDangar your answer is wrong. Atleast change your answer if you want it upvoted.

Comment: @ShafranNaizer it's okay if u dont want to upvote :)  i m asking you for that because i helped you and your question is very comman so sorry i can't upvote it

Comment: @RakeshaShastri my answer is not wrong bro i have said both the cases and when i find that he had problem of outlet then i explained him

Comment: it works with me fine

Comment: @MaheshDangar yes, then change your answer to that. You current answer is **wrong**.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri auther of question is saying that it's working fine :) but still i will respect ur optinion too and will update my answer too :)

Comment: @MaheshDangar author says your **comment** has helped him, not your **answer**, because what you have posted as an answer is **wrong** . So change your answer to what you have put as comment. Because other people who are looking for the answer won't bother reading the comments and think that you answer is **correct** and a `UITextField` text property will never return `nil`.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri yes totally agree that why I said that I will respect ur opinion and thank you very much :)

Comment: @RakeshaShastri and i have updated my answer too :)

Answer (score 0):

Connect your UILabel variable to your storyboard UILabel element